# Hibernate: Disable creating an automatic test table for C3P0

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I have access to a Remote Oracle DB where I have only read privileges.
I want to use C3P0 as connection pool for Hibernate.
The problem is that C3P0 tries to create an automatic test table, but due to read-only privileges it cannot create it and fails with a

```
WARN  [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager.java:944] An attempt to create an automatic test table failed. Create SQL: CREATE TABLE "c3p0_test_table" ( a CHAR(1) )
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

My C3P0 parameters looks like this:

```
    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</property>
```

How can I disable the creation of the automatic test table?

Comment: <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select sysdate from dual</property> ... Please add this property and try. Please refer link http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#hibernate-specific and http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

Answer (score 0):

you have c3p0 config that you aren't aware of, that is not quoted above. automatic test table creation is disabled by default. somewhere in your config, you have `automaticTestTable` set to true.

c3p0 dumps its config at INFO on pool initialization. check out the config of the pool you are actually using there and compare it to the config you expect. then look for a `c3p0.properties` file lurking in addition to the hibernate config you show, and get rid of the `c3p0.automaticTestTable=true` that has likely slipped in there.

Comment: That was what I thought but there is no such parameter... :(

Comment: have you checked the actual config of your datasource, dumped to log at INFO on pool init?

Answer (score 0):

1. check your project if there are c3p0.properties or mchange-commons.properties ,
   maybe these files contain automaticTestTable properties.
2. jinfo  $pid, check if there are jvm properties "automaticTestTable".